# Laravel route path didn't show as expected

Tags: laravel, vue.js, path, routes

```
Currently i am calling default path from laravel web route.

It should be "{{ip_address}}/"
But the result is  "{{ip_address}}/#/"
```

[image: Result]

My web.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

It is Single Page Application, laravel only return the main path in any cases, other routes will handle by vue router.

Comment: Try it with '{any}' as the preceding \ may be the issue

Comment: You've mentioned it's a SPA. Make sure Vue or whatever framework you're using does not have route redirects that could cause such behaviour.